# Check if an attribute is validated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

My problem is as follows:

I've got a form view, which needs to display success and failure icons after submit.
Before submit it just needs to show the form without the success and failure icons.

We can do this in several ways when this is the form:

```
<%= form_for @resource do |f| %>
    <div class='<%= set_class @resource, :name %>'>
        Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Check if the request is a POST:

```
    def set_class( record, attribute )
        if request.post?
            if record.errors[attribute].any?
                return "FAILED"
            else
                return "SUCCESS"
            end
        end
        # If not submitted, we don't want a class
    end
```

Set a flag after validation ( We can replace `request.post?` in above solution with `record.tried_to_validate` ):

```
    class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

        after_validation :set_tried_to_validate

        attr_accessor :validated

        def set_validated
            @tried_to_validate = true
        end

    end
```

But I don't really like these solutions..

Isn't there an inside Rails method to check if the validation process is done?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the difference between validated and passed?

Comment: Validated attributes have been tried to save.. Passed and failed attributes are valid or not after save.. Non-validated attributes have not been tried to save yet, they are viewed to the user for the first time..

Answer (score 4):

You can first test for validity..

```
@form.valid?
```

Which will generate errors stored in 'errors' on your @form. To see if errors exist on a specific field,

```
@form.errors[:some_field]
```

On your form, you can simply do:

```
<% if @form.errors[:some_field].empty? %>
  Valid
<% end %>
```

As long as some fields generate errors, the whole form will be !valid?, so you'll revert to showing the form again (:new), and you can should 'Valid' or checkmark.

Comment: I know, but when the form is build the first time ( nothing validated yet ) I don't want to view if an attribute passed validation.. I don't want to use `valid?` there because then all validations are done before the user has done anything.. If the user filled some fields of the form and submitted it, then it needs to display a tick or a cross..

Comment: Still a little confused. Forgive me. If the form is being built the first time, I would think that nothing is valid and definitely valid? would not be true.

Comment: I'm sorry, it may be me explaining it wrong.. When I call `valid?` on the first time creating the form, everything is invalid, which I don't want to show to the user.. So I need to call `errors.any?` or `valid?` only when the form is already submitted and thus tried to validate the fields.

Comment: Just for the record, this doesn't answer the question — the question is how to check if validation has been attempted on an instance at all, *not* whether or not that validation has passed or failed.

Comment: @KyleFox The title of the post is "Check if an attribute is validated" and the validation code is specifically on attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like client side validations, if want the validation to show inline on the form. http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations

EDIT

If you want to capture the 3 stages, you can save in your db. New, Validate, Finished and just use callbacks to save each stage and set the default to new. (You will have the change the data type of the validated attribute to string)

after_validation  update attribute to "validate"

after_save  update attribute to "Finished"

Then you can use an if elsif else conditions to check for the value of that attribute and render the tick and cross. Obviously, this isn't pretty and you should just use valid? and the errors? helpers.

Comment: I've got all validations working already. What I need to know is if the record is validated or not. The solution I'm using now is a method  that is called `after_validation` which sets an attribute called `validated` to true. But I don't really like this solution..

Comment: how do you want the validations to be displayed in the view? Do you have a call to error_messages in your form?

Comment: Yes, well, something like it: `raw ff.object.errors[field_name].collect{ |e| content_tag( :div, e, class: "error" ) }.join`, but after this the field is displayed.. And it needs a class 'bad' (if not valid), 'good' (if valid), or no class, if not validated yet (first time view)..

Comment: Are you saving :validate => true to your database? and it seems like you dont care which input field failed you just want to know if the whole form passed?

Comment: Thats true, I don't mind if it's the attribute thats validated, or the whole record.. I'd like to know per attribute, because it may be handy in the future.. For now, if the record tried to save itself (validations are done), that's enough..

Comment: You should be using after_dave, because after_validation will be called even if the validation has errors. There is a new_record? helper method that can test if the record has been saved.

Comment: I need it to be called if it has errors.. Look at my current 'working' solution.. It's what I need and how it should work.. But I'm looking for a nicer way, best would be per-attribute..

Comment: Right now though, set_validated is being called even if the validation fails. You can change the set_validated method to be called after_save and use the error_message helper or the valid? method to "show a tick". The validated column should also have a default value of false.

Comment: I need to know if it tried to validate, it doesn't matter if it failed or passed.. If not tried to validate, do nothing. If tried to validate, show a tick on succes, show a cross on failure..

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for helping me out here.. I think your solution should work, but it's kind of the same as what I have now, with the after_validation.. What I really need is a method like `request.post?`. I've updated my problem description, maybe it's more clear to see what I want.